# Bootstrap carousel event handling in Angular 2 / 4 / 5

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, carousel, dom-events

I am wondering how to catch event `slide.bs.carousel` (bootstrap 3 carousel) in Angular 2 and pass it to child component?

It's pretty simple in jQuery and I suppose in ng-2 too, but I cant't find simple solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: so far this `<div id="banner" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" (slide.bs.carousel)="myFunc($event)">` does not fire `slide.bs.carousel`.

Comment: One option is to move to Angular 4 and use ng-bootstrap's [Carousel component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples).

Comment: @ConnorsFan which still has the slide.bs.carousel event (or should do)

Answer (score 7):

First of all, to follow the Angular way, you need to look at Angular Bootstrap wrappers. I vote for [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap)! Add it to your Angular project as a dependency and then you could use the `CarouselModule` (the doc is [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel)).

Instead of `slide.bs.carousel` native event you would use `activeSlideChange` Angular event or play with `[(activeSlide)]` model. This could be done for example via setter interruption:

```
public myInterval: number = 1500;
private _activeSlideIndex: number;

get activeSlideIndex(): number {
  return this._activeSlideIndex;
};

set activeSlideIndex(newIndex: number) {
  if(this._activeSlideIndex !== newIndex) {
    console.log('Active slider index would be changed!');
    // here's the place for your "slide.bs.carousel" logic
  }
  this._activeSlideIndex = newIndex;
};
```

Where the template is just:

```
<carousel [interval]="myInterval" [(activeSlide)]="activeSlideIndex">
  <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
    <img [src]="slide.image">
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the `ng-bootstrap` angular wrapper because that contains the builtin directives and API that will help to manage the carousel state,event,and configurations.

If you look at this [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples) that will help you further.

for example

```
<ngb-carousel>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=4" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>10 seconds between slides...</h3>
      <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=5"  alt="Random second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>No keyboard...</h3>
      <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=6" alt="Random third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>And no wrap after last slide.</h3>
      <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

On your TypeScript File

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbCarouselConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-carousel-config',
  templateUrl: './carousel-config.html',
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig] // add NgbCarouselConfig to the component providers
})
export class NgbdCarouselConfig {
  constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
    // customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
    config.interval = 10000;
    config.wrap = false;
    config.keyboard = false;
  }
}
```

and more API please refer this [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api) . i hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use native element from carousel to catch the slide.bs.carousel event.

In your carousel div tag put the reference #carousel.

```
  < div id="carousel"  #carousel class="carousel carousel-dark slide"   data-bs-ride="carousel" >

     < div class = "carousel-inner" >

          < div class= "carousel-item custom-carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000" >
             ...
          < /div>

     < /div>

  < /div>
```

In the ts file use viewChild and fromEvent to catch slide.bs.carousel event.

```
 @ViewChild('carousel', { static: true }) carousel: ElementRef;

 ngOnInit(): void {

     fromEvent(this.carousel.nativeElement, 'slide.bs.carousel').subscribe(( data : any)=> {

          // code of event

     });

 }
```